# Rust - return a mutable reference to an element in Vec owned by a struct

Tags: rust

Here is my struct:

```rust
pub(crate) struct Graph {
    outbound: HashMap<isize, Vec<isize>>,
    inbound: HashMap<isize, Vec<isize>>,
    edges: Vec<Edge>,
}
```

and what I tried:

```rust
fn get_edge_mut(&mut self, from_id: isize, to_id: isize) -> Result<&mut Edge, GraphError> {
    let mut edges = self
        .edges
        .iter_mut()
        .filter(|edge| edge.get_from() == from_id && edge.get_to() == to_id)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    match edges.len() {
        0 => Err(GraphError(format!(
            "edge from {} to {} does not exist",
            from_id, to_id
        ))),
        1 => Ok(edges[0]),
        _ => panic!(
            "wrong graph structure - edge from {} to {} exists multiple times",
            from_id, to_id
        ),
    }
}
```

The problem is here: `Ok(edges[0])`

It fails with `cannot return value referencing local variable "edges"`

I understand that `edges` is owned by the current function and I cannot return a reference to it because it goes out of scope, but what would be a better way to return a mutable reference to an element in the "edges" Vec (of the struct) based on some condition?

Comment: Please try to create a [mre]. I think `edges.pop()` would work here instead of `edges[0]`, however, it's hard to say for sure without being able to test it.

Comment: Consider using an adjacency matrix instead of adjacency lists -- a matrix scales as n^2, but lists have a *lot* of overhead for small n / dense graphs and are also much slower to access. If you do have really big sparse graphs, possibly there's a sparse matrix library that could help keep your memory usage reasonable. Of course, you could also just use `petgraph`, depending on what your specific needs are.

Comment: @trentcl efficiency is not my problem, I just want to get that element as a mutable reference :) but it won't compile this way and I am looking for alternatives

Comment: Instead of getting directly the mutable reference, you can find the index of the edge then return the mutable reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using:

```rust
    fn get_edge_mut(&mut self, from_id: isize, to_id: isize) -> Result<&mut Edge, GraphError> {
        self.edges.iter_mut()
            .find(|edge| edge.get_from() == from_id && edge.get_to() == to_id)
            .ok_or(GraphError(format!("edge from {} to {} does not exist", from_id, to_id)))
    }
```

It skips your "wrong graph structure check", but if it's needed, you could go with

```
fn get_edge_mut(&mut self, from_id: isize, to_id: isize) -> Result<&mut Edge, GraphError> {
    let mut edges_matching = self.edges.iter_mut()
        .filter(|edge| edge.get_from() == from_id && edge.get_to() == to_id);

    let edge = edges_matching.next()
        .ok_or(GraphError(format!("edge from {} to {} does not exist", from_id, to_id)));

    assert_eq!(edges_matching.count(), 0,
               "wrong graph structure - edge from {} to {} exists multiple times",
               from_id, to_id);

    edge
}
```

It seems like the issue might stem from `edges[0]` ultimately calling `SliceIndex::index`, which basically returns an `Option<&&mut Edge>`, where that first `&` is actually a reference to the current function.

trendcl is right, `edges.pop()` works too.